# Decomposition an $A$-module to irreducible ones

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, vector-spaces, modular-representation-theory

Let $V$ be a complex vector space (i.e, over the filed of complex numbers) and $A$ be a  complex algebra.

Suppose that $V$ is an $A$-module. Under what proper condition(s) there are irreducible submodules $V_i\leq V$ satisfying the following conditions?

1. $V_i\cap V_j=0$,
2. $V$ is embedded into $\prod V_i$

Comment: What do you mean by 2? Does the embedding have the restrict to the natural inclusions $V_i \hookrightarrow \prod V_j$? It seems more natural to ask for the natural map $\bigoplus V_i \twoheadrightarrow V$ to be surjective (or use quotients instead of subobjects and dualise).

Comment: Yes, by the natural inclusion $V_i \hookrightarrow \prod V_j$ for every $i$.

Comment: You did not answer my question. Are you requiring that the restriction of said embedding agrees with the natural inclusion?